# Eclipse Juno android proposals/autocomplete dissapearing

Tags: android, eclipse, autocomplete

im not getting any proposals on ctrl+space when im in onClickListner(){}
outside it it works fine

i have tried:
cleaning & restarting
Windows->Preferences->Java->Editor->Content Assist->Advanced (checked all, unchecked all & restore default)

it seems to not work on any kind of

```
new Someting()
{
    public void doSomething()
    {
        //proposals stop working...
    }
}
```

quick fixes in case of error still works
example: getActibity()
quick fix: Change to getActivity()

this is a workaround that works

```
onCreate(...)  
{  
    new Something()
    {
        public void doSomething()
        {
            //proposals stop working...
            otherDoSomething();
        }
    }
}  
private void otherDoSomething()
{
    //proposals start working
}
```

Other interesting thing i just noticed...

```
new OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick()
    {
        //Proposals does not work
    }
}
new OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick()
    {
        //Proposals does work if i do not add any '}'
```

Comment: it has nothing to do with my spelling abilities.  
it just stopped giving proposals when im in the onClick function

Comment: You should move to [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)

Comment: wierdest error ever. i will rewrite everything and se if the same problem pops upp again

Comment: and IntelliJ IDEA was slower and gives error on things that should not give errors. did not look to deeply into it though

Comment: I have this exactly issue. Did you ever figure it out? Just started happening on existing code that has had auto-complete in blocks for years. :(

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem couple of weeks ago. This is what I did. I was trying to use struts and I had the struts.jar file in my library. But the IDE just wouldn't give any suggestion when I pressed CTRL+space.

I solved it by putting the struts.jar file in the build path. I hope this works for you too.

This is one way to put a jar in your classpath.

Right click on your project ---> Properties ---> Java Build Path----> "Libraries" tab ---> Add JARs ----> Browse to the jar files---> click "Ok"

Comment: its not 1 kind of proposals that doesnt show.  
no kind of proposal show for anything

Comment: Did it use to work before? Did you just now do a fresh eclipse install?

Comment: it used to work. and i just tried to install eclipse again to see if that would work, it did not...

Comment: So I would still suggest you to do the same thing.. Download a jar file that you're familiar with, put it in your classpath. And see if it autocompletes it for your when you access a class in the jar

Comment: That's all I have.. Sorry. Let us know if you do figure out the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this in the past by restarting my Eclipse instance.

Comment: Well, that would do it.  Sorry I don't have a better suggestion (but understand your frustration).

Answer (score 0):

Close eclipse and delete the .metadata folder for your workspace. Fire eclipse back up and reconfigure your workspace, the .metadata folder will be automatically recreated.

Answer (score -1):

It starts working again when i write it like this:

```
new OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick()
    {
        //Proposals works again
    };
};
```

did not get any errors or warnings about the ';'
and never needed them before
and it still compiled without them

Comment: and now it works without the extra ';'. it makes no sence what so ever